# Whether the array should render four times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

The following code renders the retrieved array 4 times in the console. It seems to me that in the development version this is normal behavior due to StrictMode. Am I right?

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const ExternalData = () => {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=> {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
            .then((res)=>res.json())
            .then((users)=>setUsers(users))
    },[])

    console.log(users);

    return (
        <ul>
            {users.map(item=><li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default ExternalData;
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, your import should contain react.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
```

Yes, it is due to `React.StrictMode`.

First time when `console.log(users);` runs, when react renders dom. Output should be `[]`.

Second time when `console.log(users);` runs, when useEffect runs after first render and calls `setUsers(users)`. This makes the dom rerender, but useEffect will not be called again, as an empty array is passed as a second argument. Output should be `(10) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`.

If you use React.StrictMode, then this whole process happens twice. Initial render runs twice and then rerender after useEffect runs twice, becuase there is the `setUser` which runs twice in strict mode.
[Source](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/react-strict-mode#:%7E:text=the%20dust%20here.-,It%20runs%20code%20TWICE,-Another%20thing%20that)

Thus, the consol shuld have:

```
[]
[]
(10) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
(10) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-demo-uwywpy?file=/src/App.js